# Replace all keys in a JSON object one by one with my own data

Tags: javascript, json, loops, reactjs, react-native

I have a JSON object with the following content:

```
[{
    "type": "pdf",
    "size": "1mb",
    "date": "392017",
    .....500 more key value pairs like this
}]
```

This is how I am displaying my above JSON object on the screen in React Native.

```
export const MyComponent = ({myJson}) => {
    const data = Object.entries(myJson).map(([key, value], i) => {
        if (value !== '' && value !== null) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.body} key={i}>
                    <Text style={styles.labels}>{key}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.values}>{value}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
    });

    return (
        <View>
            {data}
        </View>
    );
};
```

I want to change the keys so it would become:

```
[{
    "File Type": "pdf",
    "File Size": "1mb",
    "Date Is": "392017",
    .....500 more key value pairs like this
}]
```

How would I do that in React?

Thanks!

Comment: You would likely provide a map of old name to new, then simply assign the old property to a new property with the new name, either in a new object or in the old one then delete the old property. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a name map of oldName:newName and use it to map to an object with the new property names, e.g.

```js
var data = [{
    "type": "pdf",
    "size": "1mb",
    "date": "392017"
}];

var nameMap = {type:'File Type',
               size:'File Size',
               date:'Date Is'
};

var renamed = [Object.keys(data[0]).reduce(
  (acc, key) => {
    acc[nameMap[key]] = data[0][key];
    return acc;
  }, {})];
  
console.log(renamed);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach((key)=>{ //this will return array of keys

   yourObject[newKey] = yourObject[key]; //saving reference in your new key.
   delete yourObject[key]; //deleting old key;

});
```

You will need to map you old keys with new ones, and then in loop you and easily change this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the var array is your JSON array and newArray is the array that you want get here is a code that can help you.

```
var array = [{
    "type": "pdf",
    "size": "1mb",
    "date": "392017",
    .....500 more key value pairs like this
}]

var newArray = [];

newArray = array.map(function(item){
    return {
        "File Type": item.type,
        "File Size": item.size,
        "Date is": item.date
    }
})
```

The map method will transform every item in the array and result for another array.

Comment: This should be a manual process, how javascript will know what should be the key?

Comment: assuming that 1 to 1 mapping exists between two arrays i.e old and new keys then it isn't necessary...whether the mapping is in `object` or `array` will work perfectly fine.